# Pass field value from ResolverQuery to resolver

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I have a ResolverQuery which has an id value, and I am doing a lookup using a datasource. Trying to pass the value of this field from the to the resolver and do a lookup using that value. What is the best way of doing this?

```
    schemaResolver.addResolverQuery('query', (_, args, { dataSources: { dataSource} }) => dataSource.findById({
    id : args.id
}));

    schemaResolver.addResolver('type', {
    field: (request, _, { dataSources: { dataSource}  }) => dataSource.getPerson({ id: request }),
});
```

So in summary trying to pass the value of the field in the resolver query (id: args.id) into the resolver lookup function( id: request)

Comment: Hi,  you can use graphql context object to pass id details into resolver... if you are using apollo it gives you a context obejct in which you can inject that value

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I got it by creating an object in my query and returning that and then using that in my resolver

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using an object in my query and passing it to the resolver. I don't think it's the best solution but it worked.